# How to detect a buggy DataContract class?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontract

Is it possible to detect the following situation (with a compiler warning or with an external tool):

```
public class SomeItem
 {
     public string ValueOne { get; set; }
     public string ValueTwo { get; set; }
 }

[DataContract]
 public class Response
 {        
     [DataMember]
     public List<SomeItem> Items { get; set; } //A desirable warning: SomeItem is NOT a DataContract, SomeItem has no member with the DataMember attribute.
 }
```

The problem is that this code can be compiled without an error or a warning, but it doesn’t work properly: Items will always be empty.

Comment: You can write "unit tests". I put it in quotes because I'm not sure it follows the strict definition of what a unit test is, but I have written lots of code quality tests using unit test frameworks. I would use reflection to find all types tagged with DataContract, then ensure all properties have DataMember, and if the types of those properties are types defined in your assemblies, ensure those types also have DataContract/DataMember, etc.

Comment: Serialization always works.  The issue is with deserializing data when the data doesn't match the classes.   When you modify the database or the classes you must also update the mapping between the c# classes and the database.  Then old export (serialize) data will not deserialize.  The fix is to make sure when you do updates that you design the updates to be forward backwards compatible.  I always say that a database must contain a version number so you can maintain forward/backward compatibility.

Comment: I don't even dream to dare to doubt that "serialization always works". But if SomeItem isn't a DataContract Response.Items is empty. Adding the DataContract attribute to the SomeItem class declaration makes it possible to transfer data with the Items member successfully.